# Unsigned char* and reinterpret_cast question

Tags: casting, char, unsigned

This is a question for a University course that I only understand about half of.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printArray(double* array, int array_size) {
    cout << "Array: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    double d[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    unsigned char* uchar_ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(d);
    printArray(d, 5);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(double); j++)
            uchar_ptr[i * sizeof(double) + j] = 1;
            
    printArray(d, 5);
} ///:~
```

I understand that this program is creating an array of type double and printing its contents in the first function. Not sure what Main is doing.

My question is.

1. What exactly is unsigned char*
2. What exactly is 'reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(d)' doing
3. why is it 'double* array' and not just 'double array'

the question the text book asks is 'Why do you think each element was not set to the element 1?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi bot. I really don't know how I can make this anymore specific but thanks for the help.